# How to use named pipes in C# correctly -- several connections, server recreation etc

Tags: c#, named-pipes, interprocess

I need to implement an inter-process communication between C# applications. I decided to use named pipes and wrote the following code:

**Server**

```
while (true)
{
    using (var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("some_pipe"))
    {
        server.WaitForConnection();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(server))
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            MessageBox.Show(line);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
using (var client = new NamedPipeClientStream("some_pipe"))
{
    client.Connect();

    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(client))
    {
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
        writer.WriteLine(path);
        client.WaitForPipeDrain();
    }
}
```

I have the following questions about it:

- Is this solution correct at all? Is there any issues or bugs you already see?
- What will happen if the second client will try to connect to this server? Will it wait for the first client to finish or just send its message along with another client's instance resulting in garbage?
- Should I really create another instance of `NamedPipeServerStream` class every time? If I move its construction from the `while (true)` loop it gives me an exception "Cannot access a closed pipe". How can I avoid it? If I can't avoid it and should re-create this object every time, what will happen if there is no `NamedPipeServerStream` at the moment when client will try to connect to it?

Comment: I'd put the server pipe in it's own `AppDomain`.  Network clients can prevent the server from re-creating the pipe if they are still using it. Unloading the domain and the pipe gets around that

Comment: @Micky Duncan Can you give me an example pls?

Comment: I tried the same thing...It seemed that the client is closed when the StreamWriter is disposed.

Answer (score 11):

This will not work. Multiple clients connecting to just one NamedPipeServerStream is a feature not available. Its name with "...ServerStream" is misleading. Pipes are 1 to 1 connections. You must have multiple server instances serving the same pipe for many clients. [This Code Project shows how to implement a Server Pipes and  may help you](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/864679/Creating-a-Server-Using-Named-Pipes).

Comment: But [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762927(v=vs.110).aspx) it says "Named pipes can be one-way or duplex. They support message-based communication and allow multiple clients to connect simultaneously to the server process using the same pipe name".

Comment: @ensisNoctis To the same server *process*, not the same `NamedPipeServerStream`. The server process needs to start as many `NamedPipeServerStream`s as there are clients.

Comment: Multiple streams is not the same as the answer suggestion to start multiple server instances (ie apps) which makes it rubbish